# I'm Trying to find power of 2 numbers and modulo of it ((x**y)%z) with math.pow and its giving an Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have 3 Variables And I want to find `(x**y)%z`. I Have Imported math Library and called `math.pow(x,y,z)` still it is giving me error

Error Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    math.pow(x,y,z)
TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

I'm Using Python 3.9.1

Comment: Apply the modulus to the result of `math.pow`...

Comment: There is no reason not to use the built-in `pow` function which does accept three arguments.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the problem is that it doesnt accept three arguments

Comment: @Luke_: yes, it does. `math.pow` is not the same as the [built-in pow function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

Comment: Oh ok, i didnt expect pow to have a modulation option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I Have 3 Variables And I want to find (x**y)%z. I Have Imported math Library and called math.pow(x,y,z) still it is giving me error*

You can do it using built-in (no need to import anything) function [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) for example:

```
print(pow(2, 10, 10))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Using 3-arged `pow` can be more efficient than using `**` and then `%`.

Answer (score 1):

That expression would be

```
math.pow(x, y) % z
```

as the error is correctly telling you, `math.pow` only takes two arguments which are to implement `x ** y`. You can then use the result of that to take the modulus.

Comment: You can also just simply use the ** operator

Comment: @Luke_ Yes you can, I used `math.pow` since the OP was specifically asking about using that function.

Comment: Passing 3 arguments to ```pow``` is faster that finding power and mod next. I got confused with builtin ```pow``` and ```math.pow```.

Answer (score 1):

Pow can only be used to do x to the power of y (math.pow(x, y)) so passing 3 parameters doesnt actually make sense to pyhton.

Instead what you should do is simply:

```
answer = (x ** y) % z
```

Since python has support for ** as to the power of, and % as modulus.

If you for some strange reason rly do want to use math.pow, you should leave the z argument out of it like this:

```
answer = math.pow(x, y) % z
```